# In a batch file, set variables from lines in a file containing spanish characters

Tags: file, variables, text, batch-file

I found on this site this useful script to assign values to variables from lines in a txt file.

```
@echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set vidx=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (caplist.txt) do (
    SET /A vidx=!vidx! + 1
    set var!vidx!=%%A
    echo %%A
)
set var > test.txt
pause
```

It works fine but the lines in my text file contain spanish characteres like ñ, é, etc.
Lines in test.txt are OK but the echo in the for loop displays exotic characters.
BTW, I obtain the same effect just doing a simple Type command of the file.

Can somehone help? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

that's because the terminal window that is displaying the output of cmd.exe is using a different codepage that the characters in caplist.txt are encoded in.

Probably they are encoded using either ISO 8859-1 or UTF-8.

Try `chcp 1250` at your terminal, to see if this fixes your problem.

If not, dump the text file in hexadecimal and figure out the encoding used, and set the terminal code page accordingly.

Comment: In fact I asked a similar question here regarding set -p  and the answer provided by rjjj solved the problem with the chcp 1250. Of course I tried a similar approach with this new problem  but failed. I don`t know how to dump the text file.

Comment: it might be encoded in another codepage, then; or probably in UTF-8, although this is not technically a codepage. Where does the original txt file come from? how it is produced? with an editor? which editor? To dump a file, use a hex dumper or hex editor, you might find dozens out there. Or try `debug file.txt` and then `d`.

Comment: I created the file with Notepad

Comment: Programming a batch file is a nightmare especially if you use spanish characters. I just started learning AutoHotKey that seems so easy especially for a newbie like me. Anyway, many thanks to all of you for the help.